# What is proper way to chain a future without transforming it?

Tags: java, asynchronous, future

Suppose I have 2 functions that return a type of Future.

```
ListenableFuture<User> createUser();

CompletableFuture<BillingAccount> createBillingAccount(User user);
```

I need to run `createUser()` before running `createBillingAccount` because it depends on the user created.

However, I want to return the user, not the billingAccount.

Normally, I would use `Futures.transformAsync(createUser(), user -> createBillingAccount(user))` but this would return a BillingAccount. I want to return a user.

What else can I do here without blocking?

Comment: `transformAsync(createUser(), user -> { createBillingAccount(user); return user; })`?

Comment: Or `whenComplete`.

Comment: @shmosel don't think that'll work. `createBillingAccount` is a Future, so I need something to activate it. I don't want to call a blocking `.get()` on it

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- same question, how would I run the `createBillingAccount` future? I don't want to call `.get()` on it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply execute the future and then do `thenApplyAsync` and return the user, so that you are returning a future of User, and discard the billing, like this:

```
Futures.transformAsync(createUser(), user -> createBillingAccount(user).thenApplyAsync(b -> user))
```